# Ionic capacitor local notifications

Tags: capacitor, ionic6

I have ionic capacitor application and used @ionic-native/local-notifications to add local notifications. After updating the capacitor to the latest version (v4) I also updated my notifications and now I use @capacitor/local-notifications. Now If I install my updated app apk and set the notification the app closes. I used `adb logcat` and saw that I get this error

`03-03 22:50:38.800  1935  2296 W AlarmManager: Maximum limit of concurrent alarms 500 reached for uid: u0a631, callingPackage: app 03-03 22:50:38.801 25771 25847 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CapacitorPlugins 03-03 22:50:38.801 25771 25847 E AndroidRuntime: Process: app, PID: 25771 03-03 22:50:38.801 25771 25847 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 03-03 22:50:38.801 25771 25847 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$callPluginMethod$0$com-getcapacitor-Bridge(Bridge.java:730) 03-03 22:50:38.801 25771 25847 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:8) 03-03 22:50:38.801 25771 25847 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)`

and when I run `adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep app` I see that there are a lot of notifications sets.
`tag=*alarm*:app/com.capacitorjs.plugins.localnotifications.TimedNotificationPublisher reason=alarm_cancelled elapsed=-14m15s364ms rtc=2023-03-05 15:59:54.989]`

I tried to remove them. And used this code to get pending notifications LocalNotifications.getPending() but I get an empty array and I cannot clear them, do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

I tried to remove them. And used this code to get pending notifications LocalNotifications.getPending() but I get an empty array and I cannot clear them, do you have any idea how I can fix this?